# Sorting an Array by Last Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A list of authors (first names and last name) is giving out and it is placed in an array. The request is How to Sort by Last Name.

I try, but it sort by first name (because first names are in front).  Is there any way to sort a second word?  Please give me a hand.  Thanks!

[JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/6w4kc/)

HTML

```
 <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>AUTHOR NAME</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

JS

```
var authors = ['Ernest Hemingway',
                'Charlotte Bronte',
                'Dante Alighieri',
                'Emily Dickinson'];
authors.sort();
for ( var i=0; i<authors.length; i++)
{
    var tr="<tr>";
    var td="<td>" + authors[i] + "</td></tr>"
    $('#myTable').append(tr+td);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this shoud work for you

```
authors.sort(function (author1, author2) {
    return author1.split(' ')[1] > author2.split(' ')[1];
});
```

Because by default it will sort by first name. You have to tell sort function how you want to sort this array.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do a custom sorting like

```
authors.sort(function (obj1, obj2) {
    var s1 = obj1.split(' ')[1],
        s2 = obj2.split(' ')[1];
    return (s1 || obj1).localeCompare(s2 || obj2)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B9RWf/)

Note: I'm assuming the last name will be the text after the first space character in the name

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) you may want to consider the following:

```
authors.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.split(' ')[1] > b.split(' ')[1])
      return 1;
    if (a.split(' ')[1] < b.split(' ')[1])
      return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
string[] strNames = { "Daenerys Targaryen", "Jon Snow", "Tyrion Lannister", "Joffrey Baratheon" };

var names=  strNames.OrderBy(s => s.ToString().Substring(s.ToString().Trim().IndexOf(' '),s.ToString().Length- s.ToString().IndexOf(' ')).Trim()).ToArray();
```

Comment: OP talks about javascript, not C# and LINQ. Also code-only answers aren't very useful. It's the explanation behind the code that matters.